# Using a known value, how can I find a two dimensional array's indexes?

Tags: c++, arrays, dictionary, multidimensional-array, iterator

Trying to learn how to make a map movement system, this is how far I've gotten:

---

This is the map I intend to traverse, each location opens a unique area, values with numbers correspond to input like N, W, E, S

---

```
  int Coordinates[3][3]{  
  {0, 1, 2} , 
  {7, 9, 3} ,   
  {6, 5, 0}   
  };
  map<string,int> Move_Table;
    Move_Table["n"]=1;
    Move_Table["ne"]=2;
    Move_Table["e"]=3;
    Move_Table["se"]=4;
    Move_Table["s"]=5;
    Move_Table["sw"]=6;
    Move_Table["w"]=7;
    Move_Table["nw"]=8;
  //Starting position updates after value is entered
  int position = Coordinates[1][1];
  string command;
  cout <<"Move: \n";
  cin >> command;
  //toLower()
  transform(command.begin(), command.end(), command.begin(), ::tolower);
  //Check if command is validly within command map (will update this later... focusing on the array bit)
  if (Move_Table.find(command) == Move_Table.end()){
    cout << "Invalid move command\n";
  }
  else {
    int Result = Move_Table.find(command)->second;
    cout << Result;

    //This should allow me to iterate through a one dimensional array, but I need to get the indices of a two dimensional one

    auto it = std::find( std::begin( Coordinates ), std::end( Coordinates ), Result );

    if ( it != std::end( Coordinates ) )
    {
        std::cout << "The index of the element with value 7 is " 
                  << std::distance( std::begin( Coordinates ), it )
                  << std::endl;
    }
  }
```

After which, I update the player position with the new x and y coordinates I find. So, those coordinates are room specific for the time being, I haven't thought of a grander way to plot this map but this should do as a test. (Was suggested to use graphs, not familliar with that idea yet)

Basically, if the result wants to search the multi for a 1 (north), it should return a (x=0,y=1)

---

Sorry for the lack of indentations, I'm coding on repl.it.

Comment: `int Coordinates` is missing the values 4 and 8. Is this intended?

Comment: instead of storing an index to an array in the map, you could directly store the (x,y) pair in it: `map<string,pair<int,int>> Move_Table{{"n",{0,1}}, [...]};`

Comment: Ooh, I like this idea @TomasDittmann, I'm not sure how to pull the pairs out of the map if they're nested like this though? So I know to get the pair I get use...  `Move_Table.find(command)->second` right? How does it work for a nested pair if I want to store x and y in an integer variable?

Comment: The pair itself again has `first` & `second` members. 
So x would be `->second.first;` and y would be `->second.second;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use simple `for` loops:

```
int x, y;
int found = 0;
for (x = 0; !found && x < 3; x++) {
    for (y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
        if (Coordinates[x][y] == search_value) {
            found = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
}
if (found) {
    printf("x = %d y = %d\n", x, y);
} else {
    printf("Not found\n");
}
```